# Enterprise Architect reverse engineering association with shared_ptr<TYPE>

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to reverse engineer some code in EA.
I have a class that holds a member `shared_ptr` to an object of another class.
How can I make EA show this relationship ?

I've tried setting the `shared_ptr` class with the **Set Collection Classes** option, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are having stem from the fact, that shared_ptr is a template.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663239/use-the-c-stl-in-enterprise-architect), where the STL collection classes are defined and the question is similar to your issue.